# Dynamically add multiple fields to be validated using bootstrap validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have gone through the example [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/adding-dynamic-field/). But it illustrates dynamic addition of a single input field. I have to add multiple dynamic input fields. How can I achieve it? Refer this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7oz1mamL/)

I need to dynamically add all the three fields in the table row on clicking button through.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethings like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="myAction">
    <div class="row" id="line_1">
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="idFirstField_1" name="firstField[]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="idSecondField_1" name="secondField[]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="idThirdField_1" name="thirdField[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="cloneButton">add line</a>
</form>
```

In the JavaScript file you must to use the function clone() and to change the id of each input if you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 2;
    $('#cloneButton').click(function () {
        var klon = $('#line_1');
        klon.clone().attr('id', 'line_' + (++count)).insertAfter($('#line_1'));
        $('#line_' + count).children('div').children('input').each(function () {
            $(this).val('');
            var oldId = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
            $(this).attr('id', oldId[0] + '_' + count);
        });
    });

//if you want to validate the fields, then you can use this code: 

    $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
            'firstField[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Enter a value'
                    }
                }
            },
            'secondField[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Enter a value'
                    }
                }
            },
            'thirdField[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Enter a value'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now the bootstrap validation does not will work for cloned fields because you must to use in the JavaScript file somethings like this

```
$('#myForm').bootstrapValidator('addField', $option); //(from your link http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/adding-dynamic-field/ )
```

but who will contains all fields. I don't now how to do it.

Comment: This is where I am stucked.